# Allow User to edit profile

Tags: django, django-forms

So this is what I have so far:

In Views.py

```
class ProfileUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = User
    fields = ('username','email', 'password1', 'password2')
    template_name = 'editprofile.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user
```

in the editprofile.html

```
<form method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

in the urls.py

```
url(r'^profile/', ProfileUpdate.as_view(), name='profile'),
```

So my problem is that this is bringing up every possible to option connected to the user profile (they can make them selves superUser, ect.)

I know this must be a simple change, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Note that your use of `fields` in your `UpdateView` is correct according to current documentation, but that this option is not supported until Django 1.6 (currently in beta). Also, `User` doesn't have the fields `password1` and `password2`, only `password` (and you don't want to use that in a form as it contains the hash, not the password), so in this case you'll have to supply a custom form anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, there is no `exclude` option in `UpdateView`

You can define a form that [`exclude`s the fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use)

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email', 'password1', 'password2')
        # or 
        #exclude = ('is_superuser',) #and whatever else you wish to exclude.
```

and then use this form in your view

```
class ProfileUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'editprofile.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user
```

And refer to [this documentation for validations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user), if needed

Comment: I reckon that explaining how to show fields, rather than how to exclude them, fits best the OP case (since he's seeing a bunch of fields he doesn't want to see, in opposition as just one). Update that, get my upvote, celebrate :P